# Is it possible to Convert or wrap C# APP to IO Xcode Apple APP and Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, xcode, xamarin

I have an app developed for windows 10 on C# and now I want to move to IOS and Android. I have heard of xamarin and used some of there stuff in C# but would it be possible to embed the C# code and move it to apple xcode without having to redevelop the app from again?

Comment: you can't directly transform windows 10 app in xamarin. I suggest  you learn Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible to embed the C# code and move it to apple xcode without having to redevelop the app from again?

No, it is not possible. Basically you can share some UIs across different platforms, but I think redevelop your app for each platform is necessary.

Not sure if you want to use Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Forms to develop your app, you can use C# for development by using Xamarin, it provides a cross-platform implementation of the extensive features in .Net framework, but the actual implementation on each system is very different. For more information, you can refer to [Understanding the Xamarin Mobile Platform](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_1_-_understanding_the_xamarin_mobile_platform/).

For Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, you can refer to [Android Architecture](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) and [iOS Architecture](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/architecture/).

For [Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/), you can have your UIs and some basic features designed in the PCL in order to share across different platforms, but for most features just for example like working with files, we need to access the native method of each platform, therefor, Xamarin.Forms provides a locator named [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to achieve this.